# Chart works uncorrectly chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kk09kw16kr)

When I try to change chart data with the top panel — it works, but when I hover on chart it changes data repeatedly. Why is this happening?

For example click on the 'week' and after that hover on the chart below.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: @Colin, sorry, I can not update the question when I add the code - it says that I need to add a little description, I add it and still does not allow updating the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was watching the CodeSandbox that you gave, and I see that you have the tooltips intersect with value : false and that I think it will use the tooltip mode all the time, and not when you want soo try to put it like this and see if it works:

```
tooltips: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: true
    },
```

Sugestion:
Add this to renderLi(refering to CodeSandbox sample)

```
onMouseOver={() => {
      this.setState({ selectedIdx: key });
      this.props.itemKey(key);
    }}
```

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Yeah, I know, but I need fast tooltip showing when hovering on the chart. It's bad :( Does it has another solution?

Comment: Well I was trying but i dont find a way to, so my advice is to keep it like that or separate the data to different charts but at the same place with a mini "custom menu at the top". Oh and add the code that I will put on the post to your sample, it looks a little bit more dynamic ;)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I answered on my question. Solution was founded, you can check it. I will not remove the tick from you :)

Comment: Yes thx for that, It might help me too, ill give a point to that! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I added chart to global scope. If chart exists and is not equal null ⇒ it will be destroyed. Corresponding flickering was vanished

```
if (window.eChart && window.eChart !== null) {
  window.eChart.destroy();
}
```